# Circle CI MySQL not available in bash

Tags: mysql, linux, continuous-integration, circleci

Using Circle CI I do the following to install MySQL:

```
      - image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ubuntu
         - MYSQL_USER=user
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

I get a successful installation :

```
MySQL init process done. Ready for start up. ......mysqld: ready for 
connections.
Version: '5.6.38'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  
MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

The problem is that if I try to us mysql for something like this:

```
mysql --version
```

I get:

```
mysql: command not found
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/221566/mysql-command-line-not-working